# WIndows name resolving

Tags: ip-address

When I ping a machine on my network I got:

```
C:\Users\HPpro>ping hunter

Pinging Hunter [fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::d969:caef:86db:271a%14:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

How does the name 'hunter' resolve to that IP address? I can not find any thing in the hosts file, but the machine can still resolve. I am wondering this for days, and got no clue.

I want to know how windows really resolve the names.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified.

First, the system looks into hosts file. But usually, there's nothing there.

Then it talks to DNS server via DNS protocol. On cmd-line type `ipconfig -all` to see DNS servers for each network adapter.

How does it know IP address of DNS server? There's more than way but most common is via DHCP protocol which is a protocol to provision network settings (gateway, DNS server etc.) from DHCP server.

How does it know IP address of DHCP server? Oh well, that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: That make perfect sense. But I still don't know why it resolves to a IP6 rather than a IP4 address.

 I want to figure how windows resolve names, because I try to figure out why WSL can not resolve the name of a remote machine within the same VPN

Answer (score 0):

`ping` works on 2 ways:

1. With IP Address
2. With Website

I believe that `hunter` is your computer name and `ping` is taking that as the hostname and showing the result in `IPV6` Address.

This information doesn't be available in the `hosts` file. You may refer [this](https://www.cdu.edu.au/itms/ipaddress-computerhost) for Windows 7 and Windows 10 to check the information from the utility.

Comment: I have no problem find my hostname and ip, I want to know how windows resolve to that IP6 instead of IP4